# "Uncompiled actionscript" error

Tags: ios, air, flash-builder, flash, external

I'm having the tittle error when I try to load a local swf file in the documents directory of my iPad. Web it works ok. the swf files have ABC code.

I'm using Air 3.7, which supposedly added a feature to allow this, however, I'm still having this error.

Maybe I'm not using the Air 3.7?, I'm using Flash Builder 4.7, and I overlaid the Air SDK following the Adobe site instructions.

I've set the swf version to 20 and I'm pointing to the new SDK folder.

Don't know what else to do.. is there a way to be sure of what version of Air is the app installed with?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

External SWFs must be specified in the [AIR Application Descriptor elements](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WS180fc5cb46642d105c891f2413da22fbc8f-8000).

> [image: air-3.7-workflow]

FileContainingListofSWFs.txt:

```
assets/Level1.swf
assets/Level2.swf
assets/Level3/asset/Level3.swf
```

AIR Application Descriptor XML:

```
<iPhone> 
    <externalSwfs>FileContainingListofSWFs.txt</externalSwfs> 
</iPhone>
```

From [External hosting of secondary SWFs for AIR apps on iOS](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2013/03/08/external-hosting-of-secondary-swfs-for-air-apps-on-ios/):

> To use this feature, developer needs to specify a text file containing
>   details of the SWF files to be stripped & externally hosted. This text
>   file contains line separated paths of SWFs, which are to be externally
>   hosted.

Comment: Yes I'm doing all of that, external file added, Air 3.7, etc.. However, I'm still getting the error. What else can I try?, is there a way to know for sure what version I'm installing in the captive runtime?, Maybe FB is for some reason not using 3.7, but 3.6, the one with FB 4.7.